# In JS what is the benefit of declaring a variable name before assigning a value to it?

Tags: javascript, variables, var

Normally I would declare a variable with the value like so:

`var foo = "I am foo";`

But recently I have seen the variable name declared first, and then a value assigned later like so:
`var foo;`

`foo = "I am foo";`

What is the benefit of doing it this way?

Comment: One benefit to those that used to write C is that it will resemble the code you've looked at for years and years. Variable declaration at the top of each block was once upon a time, the only way it was done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No "benefit" in particular. But certain situations call for it, most notably conditional declarations:

```
var foo;

if (bar) {
    foo = 'baz';
} else {
    foo = 42;
}
```

Using `var` both times within the `if..else` would be in error or at least misleading. If you use `let` instead of `var`, it would even scope the variable incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

The benefit only comes into play if you don't know what value you are going to assign to it, rather than re-assign a value. e.g.

```
var foo;
if(someCond){
  foo = "this";
} else if(someOtherCond){
  foo = "that";
}
```